# How can i show text saved in database embedded in textarea?

Tags: java, javafx

OK my dude is this show text saved in database embedded in textarea, I have the code to save  receive the message and send message  in the database. I just show when I'm connect the message but when I'm not connected and the I connect to the server the message disappear.

well this is my code about receive and send message:

```
public void guardaMensajeRecibido(Chat chat,Message message){
    try {

        Date d=new Date();
        Timestamp t=new Timestamp(d.getTime());

        String statusRecibido="Recibido";
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        String[] chat_array=chat.getParticipant().split("@");
        String chatt=chat_array[chat_array.length-2];
        String mensaje=message.getBody();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO  DATABASEH2.MESSAGES(USER,STATUS,MENSAJES,HOUR) "+"VALUES('"+chatt+"','"+statusRecibido+"','"+decodeBase64(mensaje)+"','"+t+"')",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        rs=st.getGeneratedKeys();

        st.close();

        //rs.next();





                //rs.getInt(1);
                //krs=st.executeQuery("select * FROM  DATABASEH2.MESSAGES ");
                //System.out.println(rs);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 public void guardaMensajeEnviado(String mensajes) {


     try {
         System.out.println("entra al metodo"); 
            Date d=new Date();
            Timestamp t=new Timestamp(d.getTime());

            String statusEnviado="Enviado";
            PreparedStatement ps=null;
            /*String[] chat_array=chat.getParticipant().split("@");
            String chatt=chat_array[chat_array.length-2];*/
            String user="You";

            System.out.println("llega para insertar mensaje st: "+(st==null?"null":"no null")); 

            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO  DATABASEH2.MESSAGES(USER,STATUS,MENSAJES,HOUR) "+"VALUES('"+user+"','"+statusEnviado+"','"+encodeBase64(mensajes)+"','"+t+"')",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            rs=st.getGeneratedKeys();
            st.close();


            System.out.println("guarda en bd");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("SQLException mensaje"+e.getMessage());  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception mensaje "+e.getMessage());    
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

}
```

and this code show when I send the message:

```
btnSend.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    String empty="";
                    String mensajes=txtMensajes.getText();

                    //decodeBase64(mensajes);
                    String[]  talkTo_array=lstDisplayBuddys.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().split("-");
                    String talkTo=talkTo_array[talkTo_array.length-1];
                    System.out.println(talkTo);

                    String user="You say: ";
                    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
                    String fecha=today.getTime().toString().substring(0,7);
                    Calendar yestarday = new GregorianCalendar();
                    yestarday.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                     String todai="____________________________________"+today.getTime()+"_____________________________________\n";
                    try {


                         if(today!=yestarday){
                             System.out.println(txtContMensajes.getText().length());
                             if(txtContMensajes.getText().length()==0){

                                 System.out.println(fecha);
                                 System.out.println(txtContMensajes.getText());
                                 txtContMensajes.appendText(todai+"\n");
                                 System.out.println(todai);
                                 System.out.println("mensajes del dia de hoy"); 

                             }



                            if(talkTo!=mensajes)
                            {

                            try {
                                    while(true){

                                         sendMessage(encodeBase64(mensajes), talkTo);
                                         System.out.println("llega a mostrar tu mensaje");
                                         txtContMensajes.appendText(user+mensajes+"\n");
                                         txtMensajes.setText("");
                                        break;
                                        }

                                    ConnectionDBH2 cdb=new ConnectionDBH2();
                                    System.out.println("llega a metodo guardar");
                                    cdb.guardaMensajeEnviado(mensajes); 



                            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                          }
                         }
                         if(mensajes.equals(empty))
                            {
                                txtContMensajes.setText("Typing something!!!\n");
                                txtContMensajes.appendText("Enter your Contact or  your message\n");
                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }
            });
```